# Window script to exit itself if command not recognized

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window

I want to write a window script to exit script if an command is not recognized as internal or external command.

May I know how to achieve that? Really need some help, as window cmd documentation and example is limited.

I have tried with :

```
somecommand
if errorlevel 0 exit /b
```

But it doesn't seem to work, as the value of errorlevel stay 0, even i got error on "command is not recognized as internal or external command"

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: windows already spits an error message like that - why do need rediscover america? :)

get list of all commands - put them in an array and in every input check if the command exists in that array - if not, spit your error message, else allow command line to execute it :) 
but let me repeat, it is a sisyphos labour, maybe worse :)

Comment: It's much easier to detect a command failing than to compare the command's name to all CMD.EXE internal and arbitrary external commands...

Answer (score 1):

Write a short batch file (a simple textfile) with

```
@echo off
%* 2>nul || echo No such command: %*
```

The `||` operator starts the next command (here `echo`) only if the previous command fails.

Answer (score 0):

The `if errorlevel n` will be evaluated as *true* for any errorlevel value greater or equal to `n`. So `if errorlevel 0` will be true for any non negative errorlevel.

When a command is not recognized, the `errorlevel` value set is `9009`, so you can try with

```
somecommand
if %errorlevel% equ 9009 echo does not exist

somecommand
if not errorlevel 9010 if errorlevel 9009 echo does not exist
```

Of couse, any existing program can set an `errorlevel` of `9009`, so this is not a bullet proof method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off  
ver > nul  
echo ERRORLEVEL : %ERRORLEVEL%    
some command  
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( goto PrintError )  

:PrintError  
echo Command is not recognized as internal or external command!  

exit /B 1
```

Comment: Can you offer some explanation of the approach you're taking? Just click "edit" below your answer, and provide details about what you're doing before the code block.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26378018)